# Take the star rating from html page using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to take the star rating from this page (https://www.edmunds.com/tesla/model-3/2019/consumer-reviews/)

I am talking about the section with Safety, Performance, Comfort and so on

Here is what html code looks like:

```
<div class="justify-content-between flex-column flex-md-row row"><dl class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-between pr-1_5 pr-sm-0 pr-md-1_5 pr-lg-0 pr-xl-2_5 col-7 col-sm-4 col-md-5"><dt class="font-weight-normal">Safety</dt><dd class="mb-0"><span class="rating-stars text-primary-darker"><span class="sr-only">5 out of 5 stars</span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span></span></dd></dl><dl class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-between pr-1_5 pr-sm-0 pr-md-1_5 pr-lg-0 pr-xl-2_5 col-7 col-sm-4 col-md-5"><dt class="font-weight-normal">Technology</dt><dd class="mb-0"><span class="rating-stars text-primary-darker"><span class="sr-only">5 out of 5 stars</span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span></span></dd></dl><dl class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-between pr-1_5 pr-sm-0 pr-md-1_5 pr-lg-0 pr-xl-2_5 col-7 col-sm-4 col-md-5"><dt class="font-weight-normal">Performance</dt><dd class="mb-0"><span class="rating-stars text-primary-darker"><span class="sr-only">5 out of 5 stars</span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span></span></dd></dl><dl class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-between pr-1_5 pr-sm-0 pr-md-1_5 pr-lg-0 pr-xl-2_5 col-7 col-sm-4 col-md-5"><dt class="font-weight-normal">Interior</dt><dd class="mb-0"><span class="rating-stars text-primary-darker"><span class="sr-only">5 out of 5 stars</span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span></span></dd></dl><dl class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-between pr-1_5 pr-sm-0 pr-md-1_5 pr-lg-0 pr-xl-2_5 col-7 col-sm-4 col-md-5"><dt class="font-weight-normal">Comfort</dt><dd class="mb-0"><span class="rating-stars text-primary-darker"><span class="sr-only">5 out of 5 stars</span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span></span></dd></dl><dl class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-between pr-1_5 pr-sm-0 pr-md-1_5 pr-lg-0 pr-xl-2_5 col-7 col-sm-4 col-md-5"><dt class="font-weight-normal">Reliability</dt><dd class="mb-0"><span class="rating-stars text-primary-darker"><span class="sr-only">5 out of 5 stars</span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span></span></dd></dl><dl class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-between pr-1_5 pr-sm-0 pr-md-1_5 pr-lg-0 pr-xl-2_5 col-7 col-sm-4 col-md-5"><dt class="font-weight-normal">Value</dt><dd class="mb-0"><span class="rating-stars text-primary-darker"><span class="sr-only">5 out of 5 stars</span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span><span class="rating-star icon-star-full"></span></span></dd></dl></div></div></div>
```

In case the code is too long I am posting a screen shot

[image: Screenshot of the tags from webpage]

Here is the code that I was using however when it comes to taking the said tags it doesn't work

```
data = []
ua = UserAgent()
header = {'User-Agent':str(ua.safari)}
url = 'https://www.edmunds.com/tesla/model-3/2019/consumer-reviews/'
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
content_list = html_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'review-item'})
for e in content_list:

  d = {'review_title': e.a.text,
                'review_content': e.select_one('p').text,
                'overall_rating': e.select_one('span.sr-only').text,
                'reviewer_name':e.div.text.split(',')[0].strip(),
                'review_date':e.div.text.split(',')[1].strip(),
                 
              }

  data.append(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['reviewer_name', 'review_title'], keep='first')
```

Basically what I would like to achieve is to have columns for each of those star ratings like for example Safety: 5.0, Performance: 5.0, Comfort: 5.0 and so on.

I was trying to use this part of the code:

```
d.update(dict(s.stripped_strings for s in e.select('span.rating-stars span.sr-only')))
data.append(d)
```

However it doesn't work. Moreover the tag that contains overall star rating and the detailed star rating has the same class as its  the difference is that those two tags are under different tags (I hope I didn't complicate it too much). Anyways I hope someone could help me with that.

**EDIT**
I edited a code a bit because it seems like the one I pasted didn't work which is strange

Comment: Those sections with Safety, Comfort and so one are in every review. Do you want all of them or just one?

Comment: Yes I want those star ratings for each review

Comment: So that each review besides having review title, review content, overall rating, reviewer name and review date I would like to also have Safety and comfort and so on and their appropriate values that reviewer has given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it would be quiet possible to use `stripped_strings` with correct selection of elements:

```
d.update(dict(s.stripped_strings for s in e.select('dl')))
```

Due to your expected output I would recommend to pick strings for `key` and `value` separatly:

```
...
d.update({s.dt.text:float(s.dd.text.split()[0]) for s in e.select('dl')})

data.append(d)
...
```

This would update your `dict` with:

```
{'Safety': 5.0, 'Technology': 5.0, 'Performance': 5.0, 'Interior': 5.0, 'Comfort': 5.0, 'Reliability': 5.0, 'Value': 5.0}
```

or in case that there is no `ResultSet` with an empty `dict`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant, thank you! I was trying to do it by myself by using this: 'rating_breakdown' : [d.text for d in e.select('.rating-stars')] however it was not ideal as some reviews don't mention for example Performance and because of that the order of a list is messed up. Regardless of that thank you very much once again